# Обработка строки в Python с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Нужно оставить в строке только буквы a-Z, A-Z, цифры 0-9, заменить все двойные(и больше) пробелы на один.
Пример

```
"Does not \operate 66.7 after & lt;# & gt; or what"-->
"Does not operate 66 7 after lt gt or what"
```

Как это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Попробовал вот так

```
splits = re.split(r'^a-zA-Z0-9', message)
return " ".join(splits)
```

Но почему-то `re.split` не работает

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Диапазоны символов в регулярных выражениях нужно брать в квадратные скобки, также нужно добавить `+`, чтобы несколько подряд идущих символов из диапазона считались одним разделителем:

```
import re

message = "Does not \operate 66.7 after & lt;# & gt; or what"
splits = re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', message)
print(" ".join(splits))
```

Результат:

```
Does not operate 66 7 after lt gt or what
```

Аналогично через `findall` вместо `split`:

```
import re

message = "Does not \operate 66.7 after & lt;# & gt; or what"
splits = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', message)
print(" ".join(splits))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать без `join` через двойную замену `re.sub`:

```
import re

text = "Does not \operate 66.7 after & lt;# & gt; or what"
print(re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub('[^\w\s]', ' ', text)))
#Does not operate 66 7 after lt gt or what
```